# How to set the default font size of tkdiff tool

Tags: ubuntu

What is the best way to set the default font size of `tkdiff`.

I tried to put in option add

`*Menu.font {Bold 22}` in the `~/.tkdiff`

but did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Edit -> Preferences -> Appearance and change all the settings where a font name is mentioned. In my case the original config was:

```
-font {{DejaVu Sans Mono} 0}
```

Change zero to the desired font size, e.g.

```
-font {{DejaVu Sans Mono} 9}
```